# Running into errors while trying to move signal to external module

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

I have two modules namely **main.v** and **signal.v**.

In **main.v**, I have a few lines of code that update 16 bit reg tx with a value corresponding to a square wave.

```
   reg [1:0] counter;
   reg [15:0] tx;
   always @(posedge clk) begin
      counter = counter + 1;
      if (counter[1] == 1) begin
        tx[15:0] <= 16'b1010101010101010;
      else
        tx[15:0] <= 16'b0000000000000000;
   end
```

This works fine. Eventually, though, I want to move this signal over to another file **signal.v**, because the signal that I pass to tx will grow steadily more complicated. I ran into errors when I try to do this. Initially, I tried to move all the above code to the file **signal.v**. Then used a wire between the two files as shown.

```
module signal(clk, get_tx);
   input clk;
   output reg get_tx;
   reg [1:0] counter;

   always @(posedge clk) begin
      counter = counter + 1;
      if (counter[1] == 1) begin
        get_tx[15:0] <= 16'b1010101010101010;
      else
        get_tx[15:0] <= 16'b0000000000000000;
   end
```

Then in **main.v**, I tried to add

```
wire get_tx;
reg [15:0] tx;
signal my_signal(.clk(clk), .get_tx(get_tx));
always @( get_tx ) begin
     tx <= get_tx;
end
```

Based on what I see in the output oscilloscope, this method isn't working, and I'm not certain why this is. The first case seems to work fine, so I don't know why it is failing when I move to the second case (the signals just look completely different). 
I would appreciate any help/advice!

Answer (score 2):

First of all will be better to understand your connections and simulate your code if you add full code with modules declarations.
 The problems are in the signal types. Try to change output to `wire`. As well you need to declare bus, not just 1 bit signal. And give an initial value to your counter (in other case it will do follow operation `'X' +1` which gives `'X'` in result and your condition `if (counter[1] == 1)` will never be achieved).

```
module signal(clk, get_tx);
   input clk;
   output [15:0] get_tx;
   reg [15:0] tx_out;
   reg [1:0] counter = 2'd0;

   always @(posedge clk) begin
      counter = counter + 1;
      if (counter[1] == 1)
        tx_out[15:0] <= 16'b1010101010101010;
      else
        tx_out[15:0] <= 16'b0000000000000000;
   end
   assign get_tx = tx_out;
endmodule
```

Next error in upper module, there you also need to declare bus rather than just one bit `wire [15:0] get_tx;`. 
 Try to fix this errors and your modules will work.

Comment: Outputs can be registers in Verilog.